Is my main panel ungrounded?
Opened up my main panel and noticed that the ground wire for the dryer is screwed to the bottom of the panel (see 3rd photo). All conduit leaving the box transports conductors for circuits that I can identify, nothing else. I don’t see any 1/4” copper wire leaving the box (or entering the ground near it). And there are no wires tied to my water main. Is my panel ungrounded?






Is that house a one-story?  Does it have a basement?  That box and conduit look to be metal.  Are they?  What's going on with the conduit going down?  I.e. where is it going.  Can you take a picture of the other end of that conduit.

Ground rod near the panel is not the only way of grounding. Connection to a metallic water main pipe used to be commonplace; can you find any evidence for that here or at the place where the water main enters the house?

Ground electrode connection to water main (or any other kind) has to remain accessible. Look for a heavy wire attached to the water pipe wherever the pipe enters the house, perhaps near the water heater.

It looks like you may have a couple of different brands of breakers in that panel which would, most likely, be a code violation and potential fire starter.
